# Isometries of S2 in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, lie-derivative

Can anyone give equations of isometries of $S2$ in spherical coordinates $(\theta, \varphi)$? In other words, we need to find isometries of $S2$ with respect to metric:
$g=d\theta \otimes d\theta+ \sin^{2}{\theta}\cdot{d\varphi }\otimes d\varphi$

Comment: Why not compose $(\theta, \varphi)\mapsto (x, y, z)\mapsto_{\text{othogonal matrix}}(x', y', z')\mapsto (\theta',\phi')$ ?